# Connection between J2me and Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, java-me

I want to connect my mobile application(J2me) with SQL Server 2008. Please help me. I'm new in j2me. I need any articles or examples about this connection.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you write a servlet/asp.net web application that talks to the SQL Server and returns just what is needed for the J2ME Application. As J2ME does not have JDBC and has memory constraints to deal with the results of an SQL. Hope it makes sense!

Comment: can you please give me any links on the same? I am trying tio use my hosting account with linux OS and MySQL to use it with my j2me app.